# Curl error: operation aborted by callback

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

So I have obviously googled the error - but PHP (PHP 7.4.4 (cli)) curl gives me the error:

`Curl error: operation aborted by callback` with the following code:

```
private function curl_post($url,$post,$file = null,$file_type = 'audio/wav'){
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if (!empty($file)){
        $post['SoundFile'] = new CURLFile(UPLOAD_PATH.$file,$file_type,$file);
    }

    // Assign POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)) echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    print'<pre>Curl (rec): '."\n";print_r($result);print'</pre>';
}
```

I control both (Ubuntu) servers and have rebooted them both. I am posting a fairly large amount of data but in the Google searching this didn't seem to be what is triggering the curl_error. Does anyone know what is causing it? It `was` working perfectly fine and then it stopped.

Additionally putting `file_put_contents(time().'.txt','log');` as a break in my receiving server **does** log the response. So its clearly landing in the right area.

Additionally what I will say is that the 2 servers talk a number of times to each other through curl (so one curls to one then back a bit). Furthermore - error 42 is the CURL response but `https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html` doesn't seem to provide much help. I've tried tracing the various calls to each other and can't see why it is breaking - it errors/breaks before the post/calls even occur.

Comment: `print_r($result);print'` ~ what is the extra `print` for???

Comment: Just allows for HTML outputting

Comment: Please put proper blankspaces after `,` and `.` and before `{` it's horrible to read parameters

Comment: @Antony - look closely at that line.... `.`

Comment: Which line sorry?

Comment: `print_r($result);print'` - notice anything that might cause an error? `.`?

Comment: The whole line reads `print'<pre>Curl (rec): '."\n";print_r($result);print'</pre>';` so no ... but equally the error is output before this point??

Comment: my fault - I misread that line - apologies for that.

Comment: Where in the target url does the request fail? Or does the target url process the request OK?

Comment: Np @ProfessorAbronsius! The initial stage processes and makes it back to the source page. I've tried to exit and output at the various stages but no output/response. Weirdly the failure happens quite early on - it would appear before the post has fully finished.

Comment: Perhaps, if you have not already [reviewed this it might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556895/operation-was-aborted-by-an-application-callback-libcurl) - It deals with a case in `C` but still might be applicable. As you are using v7.4 [this also might be useful](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I found the answer and I hope this helps anyone else in this situation. The reason being was because the file was missing on the server for the `CURLFile` (having previously been there). My code now reads:

```
    if (!empty($file) && is_file(UPLOAD_PATH.$file)){
        $post['SoundFile'] = new CURLFile(UPLOAD_PATH.$file,$file_type,$file);
    }
```

And this no longer generates the error. The key was that it errored *even before* submitting the post but the error itself wasn't that helpful until I broke it down in a separate test script and added the file element back in.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, a better approach for the **if** condition would be `if (empty($file) || is_file(UPLOAD_PATH.$file)){` so it's also evaluated as false if filename is empty.